# Transfer data from 1 .sqlite to other .sqlite file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Say, I am working on a sqlite file with tables X, Y and Z of app version 1.0.
Later, there is an ask for enhancement and I add 2 new columns in X, delete 1 column in Y and alter a column in Z table. I have some existing data in my sqlite, so when i download the new app version 1.1, I want the current data from my X,Y and Z tables from app version 1.0 to get transferred to my upgraded app version 1.1 - x,y,z tables, such that my user doesnt lose any data on app upgrade and plus he gets the updated tables/sqlite file with modified columns.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Which bit can't you do? There's lots of things here to be done, for example detect if its the first time the app is launching or not, detect if the old database is present or not, read data from the old database if present, copy the new database from the bundle to writable storage, append old data to the new database etc. Working out what steps are needed is up to you, if you have trouble with one particular part of the implementation of those steps then show what you tried and why its not working.

Comment: Launch the app -> check if existing DB exists -> If yes, copy all the data from old DB to new DB (but the new DB has modified tables)

Comment: What i am not able to do is: migrate data from old DB to new DB